# Accessing value by key in property dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Im trying to access and display the value of a dictionary where the dictionary has no real name but is a property of a class.

Currently I have an enum "Roles" with three elements (fighter, rogue, and sorcerer), and:

```
public class Adventurer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Roles Role { get; set; }
    public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{ID}" + "  -  " + $"{Name}" + "  -  " + $"{Role}";
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class Skill
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Roles, Skill> LinkedTo { get; set; }
}
```

and in another class I have:

```
    private void CreateSkills()
    {
        Skill swordFighting = new Skill() { ID = 1, Name = "Sword fighting"};
        Skill stealth = new Skill() { ID = 2, Name = "Stealth"};
        Skill magic = new Skill() { ID = 3, Name = "Magic"};

        swordFighting.LinkedTo = new Dictionary<Roles, Skill>
        {
             { Roles.Fighter, swordFighting }
        };

        stealth.LinkedTo = new Dictionary<Roles, Skill>
        {
             { Roles.Rogue, stealth }
        };

        magic.LinkedTo = new Dictionary<Roles, Skill>
        {
             { Roles.Sorcerer, magic }
        };
    }

    private void DisplaySkills(Adventurer adventurer)
    {
        adventurer.Skills = adventurer.Role.LinkedTo; // I WOULD LIKE SOMETHING LIKE THIS...

        lstAdventurer.ItemsSource = adventurer.Skills;
    }
```

Is there some way of accessing the values (skills) of the adventurer by knowing only the role (fighter/rogue/sorcerer)?

Best,
Dedoj

Comment: If there is a one-to-one mapping between `Roles` and `Skill` then you should probably have a single `Dictionary` somewhere that contains the mapping. You definitely shouldn't have `Skill` containing a `Dictionary` that contains `Skill`.

Comment: Roles is an enum. What is adventurer.Role.LinkedTo?

Answer (score 0):

Would you mean something like this?

for known Roles like Roles.Fighter:

`adventurer.Skills = adventurer.Skills
.Select(s => s.LinkedTo.ContainsKey(Roles.Fighter) ? s.LinkedTo[Roles.Fighter] : null)
.Where(s => s != null).ToList();`